# Solutions in $\mathbb Q_p$ leads to solution for congruences equations?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, congruences, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number such that $p\equiv1\pmod 3$. Let $n$ be an integer such that the equation $x^3=n$ has a solution in $\mathbb Q_p$. In fact with our assumptions, the others solution are in $\mathbb Q_p$ too. So the polynomial $X^3-n$ splits in linear factors in $\mathbb Q_p$. Can one deduce that the equation $X^3\equiv n\pmod {p^\alpha}$ is solvable (in $\mathbb Z$)  for every $a\in\mathbb N^*$?

Comment: Yes: indeed, a polynomial has roots in $\Bbb Z_p$ if and only if it has roots modulo $p^a$ for every $a\ge1$—that is essentially the definition of $\Bbb Z_p$. (You can check that if $x^3=n$ has a root in $\Bbb Q_p$, then $n=p^{3k}m$ for some $m\not\equiv0\pmod p$ and hence transfer the problem into $\Bbb Z_p$.)